# JPanel not showing my graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am having problems drawing onto a JPanel. Here's what I'm currently doing. 
I know the image is valid since I have written it to a file from this class and get the exact image I am wanting to draw, but when I try to draw it to the JPanel it seems to immediately be erased. I have tried google, but have come up dry. Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import utilities.Log;

public class Signature extends JFrame {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8908413895953622794L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel panel;
    private BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    private Signature() {
        setResizable(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 631, 338);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);



        JLabel lblDateSigned = new JLabel("Date Signed:");
        lblDateSigned.setBounds(48, 248, 91, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDateSigned);

        JLabel lblDateGoesHere = new JLabel("date goes here");
        lblDateGoesHere.setBounds(48, 262, 83, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDateGoesHere);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnClose.setBounds(521, 258, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClose);
        panel = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7148070953904995529L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (image != null) {
                    Graphics gc = this.getGraphics();
                    // gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void repaint() {
                super.repaint();
                if (image != null) {
                    Graphics gc = this.getGraphics();
                    // gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                    // gc.dispose();
                }
            }

        };

        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 600, 200);
        contentPane.add(panel);

    }

    public byte[] getImageByteArray() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] imageInBytes = null;
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.showMessage("Error processing signature: " + e.toString());
        }
        return imageInBytes;
    }

    public void setVisible() {
        setVisible(true);
        panel.repaint();
    }

    public Signature(BufferedImage image) {
        this();
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't call getGraphics() on a component in this way as the Graphics instance obtained will not persist. Why aren't you using the Graphics object supplied by the JVM in your paintComponent method instead?
- Don't add MouseListeners to JButtons. That is what ActionListeners are for.
- Don't use null layouts and setBounds as this will make your program very inflexible and difficult to update and upgrade.
- Instead read on and use the layout managers.
- Don't override `repaint()` as you are doing. It is OK to override it occasionally but not to do more drawing as you are trying to do.
- Do read the Swing tutorials as all of this and more is well explained there.

Comment: Why are they using `null` layouts :(

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels B/C I'm an idiot and have been thinking about this waaaaay to much today. Thanks for the help, that worked. I feel stupid lol.

Comment: @ReidMac: more suggestions above.

Comment: Don't override `repaint`, but that goes back to *"Don't call `getGraphics`"* (+1 by the way)